# Hook useState logs state when it should not. Example codebox included

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've linked below a sample app I made on codesandbox which increments a counter to show the problem.

When you increment the value with useReducer, it gets logged in console as it should.

But when you increment a second value, this time with useState, it also gets logged in console even though I never explicitly told it to.

This only happens if you have useReducer and useState in the same component.

How do I make it not log the state in console with useState?

I know I can compare states and not log if they match, but in my app, the state is a deeply nested object and I'd rather find another solution if it exists.

Any ideas?

[image: Edit gifted-dan-mbjuq]

```
const initialState = { valueWithUseReducer: 0 };

const useReducerWithLogger = (...args) => {
  const prevState = useRef(initialState);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(...args);
  console.log("Prev state: ", prevState.current);
  console.log("Next state: ", state);
  prevState.current = state;
  return [state, dispatch];
};

const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT_WITH_USE_REDUCER":
      return {
        valueWithUseReducer: state.valueWithUseReducer + 1
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducerWithLogger(Reducer, initialState);
  const [valueWithUseState, setValueWithUseState] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Value With useReducer: {state.valueWithUseReducer}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT_WITH_USE_REDUCER" })}>
        Increment with useReducer
      </button>

      <p>Value With useState: {valueWithUseState}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setValueWithUseState(valueWithUseState + 1)}>
        Increment with useState
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't work? Your code works as expected.

Comment: Well ideally, it would not log the state in console when using useState, only when using useReducer.

Comment: This is normal.  Your custom hook is not conditional, it will be run with every state update.  If you want to prevent the logging you'd need to implement a comparison to check if the reducer state has changed before logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected:

```
<button onClick={() => setValueWithUseState(valueWithUseState + 1)}>
  Increment with useState
</button>
```

On clicking the `button`, your component changing the state, `App` re-renders, and function body is executed.

Building [a custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) `useReducerWithLogger` is equivalent to:

```
/*
const useReducerWithLogger = (...args) => {
  const prevState = useRef(initialState);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(...args);
  console.log('in reducer');
  prevState.current = state;
  return [state, dispatch];
};
*/

function App() {
  const prevState = useRef(initialState);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState);
  console.log('in reducer');
  prevState.current = state;

  ...
  return ...
}
```

Therefore you can notice that **on every render**, `console.log` will be executed.

> "Well ideally, it would not log the state in the console when using useState, **only when using useReducer**".

You can fix it by **logging only when** the `reducer` state changes:

```
const useReducerWithLogger = (...args) => {
  const prevState = useRef(initialState);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(...args);
  prevState.current = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in reducer');
  }, [state]);

  return [state, dispatch];
};
```

[image: Edit Q-57649426-LogOnReducerState]

Comment: Thanks for that. That gave me some good insight. It escaped my mind that you can compare by reference with a useEffect. Marked as answered.